# Contents of the directory not available inside the container after mounting a volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have the following project directory:

```
project/
  build.sh
  Dockerfile
  scripts/
    script1.py
    script2.py
```

The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir /test_scripts
VOLUME /scripts /test_scripts
```

When I explore the container. I am expecting to see the contents of the local directory `/scripts` inside the `/test_scripts` within the container.

However I am running into two problems.

1. I see that two new directories are created. `/test_scripts` and `/scripts` inside the container.
2. When I cd into both directories they are empty, i.e. `script1.py` and `script2.py` files are not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A Dockerfile can't give itself access to the host filesystem.  You need to use a `docker run -v` option (which does not require `VOLUME`); or if you're trying to run a local script over local files, it may be easier to use a Python virtual environment without Docker.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the clarification. Isn't docker run -v and using VOLUME the same thing? This is just an example, what I do need is making the python files available within a folder inside the container. I could use ADD or COPY command but I was hoping VOLUME would allow me to sync the code changes without having to run the container everytime a change was made.

Comment: No.  Dockerfile `VOLUME` specifies that a given directory will always be a volume mount point, even if the operator doesn't specifically mount something there; its most visible actual effect is preventing `RUN` instructions from having an effect in that directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got it to work by doing this in command line using the -v flag. I'm curious is there a way to do the binding within the Dockerfile and not the command line?

Comment: No, that's not possible.